# Change navbar color when viewport size change Bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I just migrate to Bootstrap V4. Im customizing the starter template: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

I want the `navbar` to be transparent but change to dark when the `viewport` is `sm` and `xs`.

Im trying to change it using a breakpoint and adding a 'navbar-custom' class, but i doesn't change

```css
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    
 }



body {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  overflow: auto;
  height:  100%;

  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #E8D1E2, #7CC4FF, #FFECBD, #BF9BFA);
   background-size: 400% 400%;
   -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
   -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
   animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }

}



.navbar {
 border-top: 2px solid #C66FF4;
 width: 100%
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  
  nav .navbar .navbar-custom {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);

  }
}

.starter-template {
  padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta name="description" content="Full-Stack Graphic Designer, Illustrator, Front-End Development">
 <meta name="author" content="Liliana Orozco">
 <meta name="keywords" content="Designer, Creativity, Design, CSS, HTML5, Branding, Logotype, Illustration, Web, Advertising">
 <title>Randomood says: Welcome!</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap 4.0 cdn -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">


 <!--custom styles for this page -->
 <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
 

 <!--navigation-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top  navbar-custom">

    
   

    
    <!--Brand in navigation menu-->  
      
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Randomood</a>
     <!--Brand image in navigation menu-->
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img></a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
          
           
        </ul>
        
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->





 <!--JS, Popper and JQuery-->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy with scss in your bootstrap theme overrides:

```
.bg-dark {
    background-color: #343a40;
    @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bootstrap's `.bg-dark` class in your `<nav>`. CSS declaration of this class is :

```
.bg-dark {
    background-color: #343a40!important;
}
```

So, you are not allowed to override background-color property. In order to change the background-color property at particular screen break point, remove `.bg-dark` class using Javascript or Jquery and add your custom class which changes the `background-color` property of `<nav>`. I hope my explanation is clear to you.

Comment: I tested your code. By removing ".bg-dark", your navigation becomes transparent. That's what you want, right ?

Comment: There's other way of doing it using just CSS3 and html? / Yes i want to be transparent in md and up screen size devices. And in xs devices i want to change it to bg-dark.

Comment: Solved! I changed it using breakpoint and .navbar { background-color}